# @var and multiple types of objects

Tags: phpdoc

Quoting http://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/PHP/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.var.pkg.html:

> The datatype should be a valid PHP type (int, string, bool, etc), a
>   class name for the type of object, or simply "mixed". phpDocumentor
>   will display the optional description unmodified, and defaults to
>   "mixed" if the datatype is not present

So if the variable was supposed to be a Crypt_RSA object you'd have `@var Crypt_RSA`, per that, but what if it could be either a Crypt_RSA object or a Crypt_DSA object? At that point should you say `@var mixed`? It seems like at that point it's a bit misleading because mixed, to me, implies that it supports primitives even when it might not.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indicate different possible return types by delimiting them with pipes:

```
/** @var Crypt_RSA|Crypt_DSA a Crypt_* object, of either RSA or DSA subtype */
```

Comment: Here's how that renders in phpdoc: http://i.stack.imgur.com/og3fi.png . ie. phpdoc is adding the \'s and the -. I think it'd be nice if phpdoc replaced the | with an " or " but, none-the-less, it looks like that is indeed how it's supposed to be done. Thanks!

Comment: If you do `Crypt_RSA or Crypt_DSA a Crypt_* ...` you'll get this in the output: `\Crypt_RSA - or Crypt_DSA a Crypt_* ...`